# Ratio of Hyperbolic Tangent Function Approaching 0

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

The hyperbolic tangent function, $\tanh(x)$, goes to 0 as x goes to 0. So far, so good.

Consider the range $[0,1]$ and a real number k within this range.

A graph of $\tanh(0.1 x)$ is always less than a graph of $\tanh(0.2 x)$, which is always less than a graph of $\tanh(0.3 x)$, which is always less than a
graph of $\tanh(0.5 x)$, etc.

Individually, all these plots go to 0 as $x$ goes to 0 as expected.

However, when the fraction $\frac{\tanh(kx)}{\tanh(x)}$ is considered, the ratio seems to converge to k.

For example, as x approaches 0, the fraction $\frac{\tanh(0.5x)}{\tanh(x)}$ approaches 0.5.

Since a graph of $\tanh(0.5 x)$ is always less than a graph of $\tanh(x)$, (i.e., the numerator is always smaller than the denominator and should go to 0 before the denominator), I expected the ratio to go to 0.

The same goes for other values of $k$ as $x$ goes to 0:

The fraction $\frac{\tanh(0.3x)}{\tanh(x)}$ approaches 0.3.

The fraction $\frac{\tanh(0.2x)}{\tanh(x)}$ approaches 0.2.
etc.

It seems that, as $x$ approaches 0, the fraction $\frac{\tanh(kx)}{\tanh(x))}$ approaches $k$, for $k$ less than 1. (I have not tested it for $k$ greater than 1.)

Is there some property of which I am not aware that says this should happen? I have not found a proof, nor have I been able to derive one.

Comment: It is just L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Congratulations for your work !

Answer (score 1):

As Ian commented, L'Hospital's rule would give you the limit.

You could go further using the Taylor expansion around $y=0$ 
$$\tanh(y)=y-\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ Using it, you then have 
$$\frac{\tanh(kx)}{\tanh(x)}=\frac{k x-\frac{k^3 x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right) } { x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)}$$ Now, perform the long division to get 
$$\frac{\tanh(kx)}{\tanh(x)}=k-\frac{(k-1)k(k+1)}{3} x^2+O\left(x^4\right)\tag 1$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

**Added for your curiosity**

Sooner or later, you will learn that, at least locally, functions can be approximated using Pade approximants better than with Taylor series. Applied to your case, this would give
$$\frac{\tanh(kx)}{\tanh(x)}=k-\frac{5 k \left(k^2-1\right) x^2}{\left(6 k^2+1\right) x^2+15}\tag 2$$ For illustration purposes, I used $k=3$ and generated the following table for comparison :
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & \text{exact} & (1) & (2) \\ 
 0.00 & 3.00000 & 3.00000 & 3.00000 \\
 0.02 & 2.99680 & 2.99680 & 2.99680 \\
 0.04 & 2.98727 & 2.98720 & 2.98727 \\
 0.06 & 2.97158 & 2.97120 & 2.97158 \\
 0.08 & 2.94997 & 2.94880 & 2.94997 \\
 0.10 & 2.92283 & 2.92000 & 2.92283 \\
 0.12 & 2.89058 & 2.88480 & 2.89058 \\
 0.14 & 2.85372 & 2.84320 & 2.85371 \\
 0.16 & 2.81278 & 2.79520 & 2.81277 \\
 0.18 & 2.76834 & 2.7408 & 2.76832 \\
 0.20 & 2.72096 & 2.6800 & 2.72093
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank-you very much for that information. I have not used Pade approximations before, but have seen them mentioned a few times. In any case, the limit is confirmed, not contradicted, so I am happy knowing I was not completely wrong.

Comment: @DavidB2013. As I commented earlier, congratulations for playing with mathematics. Even if you rediscover the wheel (as we say in French), by your curiosity, you percieve the concept : here, you understood limits and I tried to go a little beyond to make you discovering that there is a path to this limit. Continue that way before you learn all the stuff in a formal manner. Good luck in your studies. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

While this is obviously a late answer, a simpler proof can be obtained by observing that as $y \rightarrow 0$, $\tanh(y) \rightarrow y$. This is a pretty uncontroversial observation, but if you want to prove it it's fairly simple. Claude's Taylor Expansion of $tanh$ in the other answer shows it clearly enough, for example.

Therefore, as $x \rightarrow 0$, $\frac{\tanh(kx)}{\tanh(x)} \rightarrow \frac{kx}{x} = k$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).